# Unable to get view server version from device 00190db410206e

Tags: android, adb

I just installed adt-bundle...

I would like to check the network traffic from a samsung galaxy s2 when I use a webapp. I thought it could be possible using Android Debug Monitor and Network Statistics.

But even though I can see my phone Online, I get this error on the console:

Unable to get view server version from device 00190db410206e

Any suggestions how to solve this or if it is possible to check the network traffic from the phone using ADM?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: May be useful this blog post:
http://blog.csdn.net/infsafe/article/details/12715419